# Pause music with a button in another scene in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, avaudioplayer

So I have a music that starts playing in the AppDelegate (when the app is loaded basically), and I want to make it stop once I press a button on my settings scene that has its own ViewController class.
How can this be achieved? How can I access the variable I have on my appDelegate class that starts the music?
Here's the code for starting the music in AppDelegate:

```
var themeAudioURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("theme", ofType: "mp3")!)

var themePlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    themePlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: themeAudioURL, error: nil)

    themePlayer.volume = 0.05
    themePlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    themePlayer.play()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass player further to the next scene. You can do this in prepare for segue method. Alternatively you can get an app delegate in another view controller and cast it to your appdelegate implementation.

Comment: How can I pass that variable to the next scene?

Comment: @PedroCabaço actually prepare for segue is not the case, as you start playing in appdelegate. There is no segues between controllers happening. So in your case you just need to do following if let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication() as? MyAppDelegate { app.themePlayer.stop() }

Comment: @PedroCabaço in the place where you expect your music to stop. Do you have IBAction or you want to do it on view controller appearance?

Comment: I'm doing it in a IBAction! I can't seem to access the themePlayer that way... My appDelegate file is called AppDelegate. Instead of MyAppDelegate I put AppDelegate right?

Comment: Yes, correct. Use your appdelegate. The code above is for example purposes, I am not aware about all naming conventions and implementation details of your app.

Comment: It does nothing or your got some error? What is an outcome?

Comment: Sure because I mistyped it :) it should be UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate

Comment: Glad that I was able to help. Please, accept as an answer. Good luck.